# Creating contingency tables from recoded variables (atomic vectors)

Tags: r

Another boneheaded request. I am trying to create contingency tables using recoded variables where any answer is coded as "1" and non-answers are coded as "0."

My original data might have looked like this: some variables are recoded from character strings, whereas others are recoded from numbers.

```
id   var1       recode    var2    recode2  ...   var250   recode250
1    "hello"     1         1         1     ... 
2    "hi"        1         <NA>      0     ...
3                0         <NA>      0     ... 
4     "hola"     1         1         1     ...
```

I have written a bit of code to do this recoding of strings, which I check using a contingency table.

```
data$recode <- ifelse((as.numeric(data$var1)!=1), 1, 0) #RECODES STRINGS
table(data$recode)
    0     1
    1     3
```

But then, I also need to recode the NA's in all of my other variables to be 0.  I tried to do this with another ifelse statement:

```
 data <- ifelse(is.na(data), 0, 1)
```

The values seem to change, but now when I try to run the same contingency table, I get the following error message:

```
  Error in data$recode : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The key issue at hand is that I *need to be able to produce contingency tables for all of my variables* (i.e. report percentages and frequencies), so help on how to correctly recode all of my NA's (within a range of columns) into 0 so would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your example code doesn't make any sense. `as.numeric` will only return NA on strings. Is that column really a factor?

Comment: All I can tell you is that, through trial and error, I've found that when I use `as.numeric()` on a factor variable that has string values with blanks instead of NA's, the blanks are returned as "1" and the strings are returned as values >1.  If there is a better way to do all of this, I'm completely open to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to coerce `data$var1` to character and then count the characters instead of using `as.numeric`. You can also use the fact that `logical` variables are binary, 
`as.numeric(c(TRUE, FALSE))` will give `c(1, 0)`.

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c('hello','hi','','lola'), 
                   var2 = c(1,NA,NA,1))

data$recode_1 <- as.numeric(nchar(as.character(data$var1)) > 0)
data$recode_2 <- as.numeric(!is.na(data$var2))
data


##    var1 var2 recode_1 recode_2
## 1 hello    1        1        1
## 2    hi   NA        1        0
## 3         NA        0        0
## 4  lola    1        1        1
```

### EDIT -- to deal with multiple columns

To do many columns at once, use the functions in `plyr`, `colwise`, `catcolwise` and `numcolwise`. These apply functions column-wise, column-wise for discrete data, column-wise for numeric data respectively

```
library(plyr)                   
recode_character <- function(.col){
 as.numeric(nchar(as.character(.col)) > 0 )
}

recode_numeric <- function(.col){
  as.numeric(!is.na(.col))
}
data_more <- data.frame(var1 = c('hello','hi','','lola'), var2 = c(1,NA,NA,1), var3 = c(1,1,NA,NA), var4 = c('again','with','','Missing'))

recoded_data <- cbind(catcolwise(recode_character)(data_more),
      numcolwise(recode_numeric)(data_more))

recoded_data

##   var1 var4 var2 var3
## 1    1    1    1    1
## 2    1    1    0    1
## 3    0    0    0    0
## 4    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: The bigger problem is not coding the OE's (that works), but that I have 250 recoded variables in which the "NA's" need to be coded as 0.  And then I need to be able to run contingency tables on these variables...